# Why do `TextField`s sometime include its parent `Container`s and sometimes not when they start being edited?

Tags: codenameone

I have a `TextField` inside a `Container`. The `Container` is in the `SOUTH` of a `Form` (`BorderLayout`). The `Form`'s `CENTER` Contains a scrollable `BoxLayout.y()` `Container`

When the bottom `TextField` is tapped on Android, the keyboard is shown. Sometimes, it cuts the `TextField`'s parent `Container` up to the `TextField`'s bottom, sometimes it doesn't. When it does cut it, the `Form`'s `CENTER` also gets pushed up, and the `Toolbar` disappears. I am trying to make sure that calling the keyboard never cuts the parent `Container` and that the `CENTER` Container doesn't get pushed up

Is there a way to guarantee that the parent `Container` is always shown so that it doesn't get cut?

Example of an instance when it doesn't get cut:

[image]

Example of an instance when it does get cut. Notice `Toolbar` is gone and `CENTER` `Container` is pushed upwards:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is really hard to tune positions for keyboard. We try to make it seamless but there are points where this is pretty difficult to control. Especially with a south placed text field which is static (not scrollable).

If you can isolate a test case that shows misbehavior here we might be able to fine tune the logic a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to prevent this consists in setting the `Form`'s `setFormBottomPaddingEditingMode(true);`. Easy fix!